# lwjgl3 window resize final event?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, window-resize

I know that you can track the window resize operation using:

```
    glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, wsCallback = new GLFWWindowSizeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int w, int h) {
            LOG.info("window resized");
            if (w > 0 && h > 0) {
                width = w;
                height = h;
            }
        }
    });
```

However, this way the invoke method gets invoked potentially Hundreds of times, and I only want the final event to store the new size in the configuration. How do I do this without using some sort of delay mechanism like a one second timer that gets refreshed on further invoke calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way GLFW callbacks are set up is so they are refreshed upon each call of `glfwPollEvents()`.  If you only want to set the configuration variables on the final update, this in and of itself is not feasible.  I would have a `void dispose()` method in which you can call this:

```
public void dispose() {
    try (MemoryStack stack = stackPush()) {
        IntBuffer width = stack.ints(1);
        IntBuffer height = stack.ints(1);
        glfwGetWindowSize(windowID, width, height);
        configuration.width = width.get();
        configuration.height = height.get();
    }
}
```

This allows for you to set the configuration data once when you want to close the window.  The draw back to this technique is if the application crashes or the `dispose()` method isn't called, the configuration data isn't saved.